# Posts query including meta and greater than date

Tags: wordpress, date

I'm struggling to get a working solution with this `wp_query`. I currently have some custom settings which are assigned to posts, one is whether or not the post is 'featured' and the second is a date and time for the post to end (no longer display in the results). I have the query working with the feature, but just need to work this end date into it, here is the query working find with the 'featured':

```
WP_Query('meta_key=skyali_feature&showposts=4&orderby=post_date');
```

The end date is set in the `wp_postmeta` table where `meta_key` is 'the_date' and the `meta_values` look like this '05/16/2013 05:24'. I would like to edit the above query where if 'the_date' has been set posts are only included if the 'the_date' is greater that todays date and time.

Here is my failed attempt:

```
WP_Query(
   'meta_key=skyali_feature&meta_key=the_date&meta_compare=>=&meta_value='
   .date('d/m/Y H:i')
   .'&showposts=4&orderby=post_date&orderby=the_date'
);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had to do something very similar recently and ended up needing to use the `meta_query` property instead.  You'll want to do something like this:

```
$today = date('Ymd');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '4',
    'meta_key' => 'the_date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'skyali_feature'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'the_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$your_custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

A few notes...

- I only needed to filter by date in my example, but it looks like you'll need to do date/time in yours.  (You can just adjust the first line for the `$today` variable using the format you wish).
- Use `posts_per_page` instead of `showposts`.  `showposts` is deprecated.
- Notice that I have included the `meta_key` twice (once at the top level of the array and once as an element in the `meta_query` array.  There's a known bug where you can't sort your results by the key if you don't include it this way.  I fought that one for a while too!

Hope this helps, have fun!

***[edit]*** Forgot to add your `skyali_feature` key back into the array.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, I tried it but got no result. Here is my version: $today = date('d/m/Y H:i');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '4',
    'meta_key' => 'the_date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'the_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem.  We're trying to compare *string* values (the output of `date('d/m/Y H:i')` isn't going to be comparable this way as a string.  How are you storing that date/time into your post?  Is it a freeform text field and you're just making sure to enter your date and time in that format?  Or is it actually storing it as a date/time (or timestamp) field in the database?

Comment: @Paul, what was the solution here? I'm using ACF and the date being output is a string, so it's all I have to sort with…

Answer (score 6):

for people using the advanced custom field plugin with a date data type, this is what you need for dates greater or equal than today:

```
    $today = date('Ymd');
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',            
        'meta_key' => 'end-date',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'end-date'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'end-date',
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '>='
            )
        ),
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
   $your_custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: I can't get this working at all. Here are my query arguments. Is it due to the date format? http://pastie.org/9433564 I wish ACF would store both the friendly date and a timestamp for these situations.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me using Advanced Custom Fields Pro v5. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

for people using [Custom metadata manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-metadata/) you'll find that a `datepicker` field is stored as timestamp.

So in a similar case the above example isn't working and you may have php sort out the value you need to compare against. And the timestamp for a day earlier at 23:59:59 it'll do the job:

```
    $yesterday = strtotime('yesterday 23:59:59');
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',            
        'meta_key' => 'end-date',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'end-date'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'end-date',
                'value' => $yesterday,
                'compare' => '>='
           )
        ),
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $your_custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

If you also want to take account of the timezone setting for the blog use [current_time()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time) as in the following example:

```
    $now = current_time('timestamp');
    $yesterday = mktime(23, 59, 59, date('n',$now), date('j',$now)-1);
```