# Sort Posts By Custom Field Date?

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I have the following code displaying evarying posts from a custom post type, however i need them displayed in date order from information put in a custom field, can this be done?

I try this code :-

```
      <?php $course = new wp_query( array ( 'posts_per_page' => '10' , 'post_type' => 'course','orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'meta_key' => 'course_date','order' => 'DESC' ) ); ?>
```

But its show me data like this :-

```
30-12-2014
28-9-2014
26-10-2014
19-12-2014
```

It must be like :-

```
30-12-2014
19-12-2014
26-10-2014
28-9-2014
```

What can i do ?!

Comment: Wordpress is sorting by the field's value as string. Please try defining the field as date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596551/posts-query-including-meta-and-greater-than-date

Comment: Noy Gabay : your link is for today ,, but i need for every day ...

Comment: Yes, the point is the logic - not the specific example..

Comment: Noy Gabay: I try but not work with me ,,,, Can you edit my code !!